# Your raw query had an incorrect number of parameters. Expected: `0`, actual: `2`. Prisma Prepared Statements

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgis, prisma

Please go soft on me this is my first time asking here questions.
I am having a scenario that is causing my query to fail when I try to template it with variables. But when I pass in the static values it works.
The first image shows a query with static values

[Code Block logic with static values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObJ6p.png)

the second image is the response of the above logic.
[Response while using static values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Yce.png)

Now observe what happens when I change the query to use the templated prepared statements.
[Templated code block with variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeL6E.png)

The response I get
[Templated code response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLUpI.png)

Comment: I don't use prisma, but I think the variables need to be outside the single quotes.  So you would need to close the quote and use `||`, much like you do already with your first point constructor.  Or, use st_point, which takes separate arguments rather than a string.